# Videojs dynamic track (subtitles) addition

Tags: javascript, video.js

Subtitles can be added on time of player initialization like

```
<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" data-setup="{}">
<source src="'.$video.'" type="video/mp4" />
<track kind="captions" src="sub.vtt"  label="user defined" />;

</video>
```

but i want to add vtt file  dynamically without page refresh or anything. How can i do that.

regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var video=videojs('my-video');
            video.addRemoteTextTrack({
                kind: 'captions', 
                label:'user defined',
                src: 'uploads/srt/'fileName' }, false);
```

will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

The text track did never get updated dynamically and after a long search, I had found a solution for my problem. When I change the video source I replace the text track and set it on mode="showing":

```
let player = videojs('first-player');
player.addRemoteTextTrack({
            kind: 'captions',
            src: 'my-track-path.vtt',
            mode: 'showing'
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same but it didn't work for me.
Adding `default: true` did the trick.
It was the same even when using in the `<track>` element.
So, this is the final configuration

```
player.addRemoteTextTrack({
    kind: "captions",
    label: "English",
    srclang: "en",
    src: subtitleUrl,
    default: true,
})
```